# How to create Library project in iOS like android

Tags: ios, android-library, ios-library

I am new in iOS development. I have created multiple library projects in Android like facebook library. Now I want to do same in iOS. How can I create Library project in iOS..

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a good tutorial which I went through last week to create a static library on iOS:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

And if you want to integrate a library through Cocoapods:

http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-cocoapods/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this will help you [Universal Cocoa Touch Frameworks for iOS 8](https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/universal-cocoa-touch-frameworks-for-ios-8/)